# Boolean DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger

I have a `ListView` that has some values.
I'd like to change `ListView`'s font color, but this code isn't working:

```
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Navi" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 

    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="603" Width="1029"
    ShowInTaskbar="True" Closing="Window_Closing" Background="#FFD6D6D6">
<Window.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DarkTheme}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

cs:

```
public Int32 DarkTheme {get; set;}
    //First init
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DarkTheme = 1;
        //Init component
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `DarkTheme` from `Int32` to `bool`.

```
public bool DarkTheme {get; set;}


DarkTheme = true;
```

Or

You can also create [Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that can be used in [Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bencon/archive/2006/05/10/594886.aspx).

```
 public class IntToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
      public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
        if (value is int)
        {
            if ((int)value) == 1)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
      }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       if (value is bool)
        {
            if ((bool)value) )
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I use this code public bool DarkTheme {get; set;}
DarkTheme = true;
And problem doesn't solve

Comment: `DarkTheme` should belong to `DataContext` and not to `MainWindow` class. If you are absolutely new, Read [this](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)